# Instrument amplifier gain setting and REF pin setting on INA232

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

I'm trying to amplify O2 sensor output KE-50 with instrument amplifier INA232. [Here is datasheet for INA232](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina2332.pdf) with 55x Gain and REF input connected with GND. After do PCB assembly, with 50mV input, voltage output is only 10mV, but my desired output is 2,75V.

Could you help me to troubleshot this issue?

[image]

Comment: @Nils Pipenbrinck which section on INA232 that say about minimum input voltage? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The INA232, when powered from 5V, has a minimum input voltage of 0.55V, so if you apply 50mV input you're operating the part out of it's specification.